# Linq to sql error inserting value

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to do an insert using linq to sql but am getting the following error
Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserID', table 'Itiss_Request.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The UserID table is the pk aswel as the identity has been set to autoincrement.
The database has 4 fields.

```
        DataClasses1DataContext dt = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        User usr = new User();
        usr.MudID = a[1];
        usr.Email = Session["email"].ToString();
        usr.Name = Session["userName"].ToString();


        dt.Users.InsertOnSubmit(usr);

        dt.SubmitChanges();
```

This is an from my context file

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_UserID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
        public int UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._UserID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._UserID != value))
                {
                    this.OnUserIDChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._UserID = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("UserID");
                    this.OnUserIDChanged();
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```
    DataClasses1DataContext dt = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    User usr = new User();
    usr.MudID = a[1];
    usr.Email = Session["email"].ToString();
    usr.Name = Session["userName"].ToString();
    dt.Users.AddObject(usr);
    dt.SaveChanges();
```